# Why doesn't my new Odoo module show up on the module list?

Tags: module, odoo

I am using Odoo v12 on Windows.
I have followed the steps in [HowTo](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html) to create a module `Saadoodoo`. My problem is that I have failed to make this new module appear on the Odoo module list.

I am using the below command

```
python.exe odoo-bin" -d SaadoIncLocal -i Saadoodoo --addons-path D:\PythonDev\Odoo
```

It seems Odoo simply ignores the commands and starts the server normally, as the module does not appear on the apps list (even when selecting developer mode).

I thought the issue may be in the addon path, so I added the module under the default Odoo path along with Odoo modules in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons` and did an apps update on Odoo interface but still problem persists. Starting and stopping the server does not help either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know about v12, but in v8 there is "update modules list" button in settings, which should be clicked to make Odoo discover new modules.

Answer (score 11):

After adding new module in the `addons_path`, you have to turn on `debug/developer` mode, goto `Apps > Update modules list`, remove `Apps` filter from search and search your module.

Don't forget to add `__manifest__.py` with proper data, which is important for odoo addons.

If still having problem, you can use `scaffold` option of `odoo-bin` to create empty module.

```
python.exe odoo-bin scaffold my_module
```

This is will create a empty module with all the necessary skeleton files in the current working directory, you can just move it to addons folder, rename the variables accordingly and files and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks, arryph.
Actually the steps above made odoo server recognize my module.
Now it wont start due to errors in my module, which i need to work on.
Thanks again.

Comment: @arryph can you help me with my question? Here is the url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55949799/odoo-custom-module-add-new-action-to-hr-module . I have offered bounty for this question also.

Answer (score 1):

There could be 2 Reasons that you are not able to see the module :-

**1.** **You have not updated the database**

**Two ways to update the database :-**

**1.1 from Terminal use this command to update the module and database**

./odoo-bin -c debian/odoo.conf -d {NAME_OF_ODOO_DATABASE} -u {NAME_OF_THE_NEW_MODULE}

**1.2. From frontend**

By activating the developer mode by going to Setting --> under the developer tools option --> Activate the developer mode

Now go to app list and select the option update app list.

**2.** **You have not configured the addons path in the debian/odoo.conf file**

Make sure that you have added the addons_path of the custom-addons folder in odoo.conf file inside debian folder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

why don't you simply use these commands

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons    
C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\python\python.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo-bin scaffold my_module --config C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo.conf
```

Comment: Please consider adding explanation about your code and your choice.

Comment: Your command does not specify which Python is used for.It is better to specify that you are using Python installed with Odoo and enter all the required paths along with the command.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to create module in odoo.

```
odoo-bin scaffold mynewmodule addons
```

directive command module-name modulepath

Answer (score 0):

Oh once your module is ready, go to the Odoo directory in windows, navigate to custom-addons and you will see a list of all the available modules. paste your new module in there. Now open the Odoo again, go to Apps, then update module list. Then search for your app in the app list. Make sure the developer mode is activated

Answer (score 0):

Have you click **Update App List** in menu Apps?
This is screenshot from Odoo 11, it should applied in Odoo 12 but may be different position.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Go to your odoo-version folder (ex: cd /home-path/odoo-09.0/10.0/11.0/12.0/13.0) where your odoo-bin file is placed (till odoo-10.0 the file is **openerp-server** but in later version the file is **odoo-bin**)
- Run the command `./odoo-bin scaffold yourModuleName destinationDirectory` (odoo_version >= 10)
- Run the command `./openerp-server scaffold your_module_name destinationDirectory` (odoo_version < 10)

please use configuration file to run odoo(it's quite easy without any mistake)

run this command: `python3 odoo-bin --save --config odoo.cfg --stop-after-init`

that will save `odoo.cfg` file  open it up and add your custom module path in `addons_path` varibale which is defined in top of configuartion file

Comment: Hi! On Stack Overflow, it's generally encouraged to focus on answering just the question that was asked.  I've trimmed your answer down to just the relevant parts.  If you want to answer how to do other things, you can always ask a question and answer it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

using mode debug, go to your apps, click update app list