# How to send an email from a button located in the action dropdown of an Odoo 11 form?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-view

I am just a newbie in Odoo. I am creating a custom module for Odoo 11. I want to add a new link in `hr.payslip` in `hr_payroll` module . So when admin will navigate to an individual Payslip, in the action I want to add a new option called *Email Payslip*. When this is clicked, it will send an email to the employee.

So to achieve this I have made my custom module named as email payslip.

The code is like this:

**init**.py

```
from . import models
```

**manifest**.py

```
{
    'name': 'Email Payslip',
    'summary': """This module will send email with payslip""",
    'version': '10.0.1.0.0',
    'description': """This module will send email with payslip""",
    'author': 'Test',
    'company': 'test',
    'website': 'https://test.com',
    'category': 'Tools',
    'depends': ['base'],
    'license': 'AGPL-3',
    'data': [
        'views/email_payslip.xml',
    ],
    'demo': [],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
}
```

Models **init**.py

```
from . import email_payslip
```

Models email_payslip.py

```
import babel
from datetime import date, datetime, time
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from pytz import timezone

from odoo import api, fields, models, tools, _
from odoo.addons import decimal_precision as dp
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError

class EmailPayslip(models.Model):
    #print 'sdabhd'
    _name = 'email.payslip'
    name = fields.Char(string="Title", required=True)
    description = 'Email Payslip'

EmailPayslip()
```

Views email_payslip.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<act_window id="email_payslip" src_model="hr.payslip" res_model="hr.payslip.line"  name="Email Payslip"/>
</odoo>
```

The above code shows the email payslip menu in the action but when I am clicking on the link it is showing the employee payslip record.

So can someone help me here? What would be the right approach to achieve this? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciated.

This is what I have got so far:

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have understood that you want to add a button in the actions section of the form of the model `hr.payslip`, created by the module `hr_payroll`.

I see that you are creating a new model named `email.payslip`. That is not necessary to achieve your purpose, check the following steps:

Modify the `__manifest__.py` of your module to make it depend on `hr_payroll` and `mail`:

```
'depends': [
    'hr_payroll',
    'mail',
],
```

Modify your XML action this way:

```
<record id="action_email_payslip" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">Email Payslip</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="hr_payroll.model_hr_payslip"/>
    <field name="binding_model_id" ref="hr_payroll.model_hr_payslip"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">
if records:
    action = records.action_email_payslip_send()
    </field>
</record>
```

This is to create a button in the actions section of the views of the model `hr.payslip`. The button will call a Python method of this model, which will be in charge of calling the pop-up to send an email.

Now let's define that method in Python:

```
class HrPayslip(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.payslip'

    @api.multi
    def action_email_payslip_send(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        template = self.env.ref(
            'your_module.email_template_payslip',
            False,
        )
        compose_form = self.env.ref(
            'mail.email_compose_message_wizard_form',
            False,
        )
        ctx = dict(
            default_model='hr.payslip',
            default_res_id=self.id,
            default_use_template=bool(template),
            default_template_id=template and template.id or False,
            default_composition_mode='comment',
        )
        return {
            'name': _('Compose Email'),
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'mail.compose.message',
            'views': [(compose_form.id, 'form')],
            'view_id': compose_form.id,
            'target': 'new',
            'context': ctx,
        }
```

Just replace `your_module` by the technical name of your module. This method will open the form to send an email, and we are telling it to load by default our custom email template, whose XML ID is `email_template_payslip`.

Now, we have to define that email template in XML. Create a new folder named `data` in the root path of your module, put inside the XML file, for example, named `email_template_data.xml`. Do not forget to add in the `data` key of your `__manifest__.py` the line `'data/email_template_data.xml'`, to tell your module that it must load that XML file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo noupdate="0">

        <record id="email_template_payslip" model="mail.template">
            <field name="name">Payslip - Send by Email</field>
            <field name="email_from">${(user.email or '')|safe}</field>                
            <field name="subject">${object.company_id.name|safe} Payslip (Ref ${object.name or 'n/a' })</field>
            <field name="email_to">${(object.employee_id.work_email or '')|safe}</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="hr_payroll.model_hr_payslip"/>
            <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
            <field name="lang">${(object.employee_id.user_id.lang or user.lang)}</field>
            <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[
<div style="font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Ubuntu, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); background-color: #FFF; ">

    <p>Hello ${object.employee_id.name},</p>

    <p>Here is your payslip from ${object.company_id.name}: </p>

    <p style="border-left: 1px solid #8e0000; margin-left: 30px;">
       &nbsp;&nbsp;Name: <strong>${object.name}</strong><br />
    </p>
    <p>If you have any question, do not hesitate to contact us.</p>
    <p>Thank you for choosing ${object.company_id.name or 'us'}!</p>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</div>
            ]]></field>
        </record>

</odoo>
```

In the `ctx` variable you have every data you added in the Python method. In the `object` variable, every field of the current `hr.payslip` record. You can use dot notation to reach any relational field. Check out other email templates to learn more about Mako language.

If you definitely want to use your model `email.payslip`, you should do almost the same process (depending on what you want exactly) and replace the `hr.payslip` references by `email.payslip` ones.

Once you are pretty sure that you are making any modification no more on your email template, you can turn the `noupdate` attribute to 1, to let Odoo users to customise the email template from the interface without losing their changes in case your module is updated:

```
<odoo noupdate="1">
    ...
</odoo>
```

Once you see the email pop-up and the template loaded OK by default, remember to check these three steps:

1. The work email of the employee of the current payslip record must be filled in (since it is the destination of the email).
2. You must have configured your outgoing mail server.
3. Check the cron task *Mail: Email Queue Manager*. It must be active and running each minute (if you want to send the email in one minute at the most), or just click on *Run Manually*. Also the parameter `force_send` could be set to *True* in the email, in order to not depend on cron jobs.

Comment: can you share some git repo for this?

Comment: This also showed me an error like Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py", line 350, in safe_eval
    return unsafe_eval(c, globals_dict, locals_dict)
  File "", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'hr.payslip' object has no attribute 'action_email_payslip_send'

Comment: Here you have a standard example of how to send a mail: https://github.com/OCA/stock-logistics-workflow/tree/11.0/stock_picking_send_by_mail. 
And here you have several examples of server actions: https://github.com/OCA/OCB/blob/11.0/addons/crm/views/crm_lead_views.xml. Combine both to send an email from a top action button.

Comment: What about this?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py", line 350, in safe_eval
    return unsafe_eval(c, globals_dict, locals_dict)
  File "", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'hr.payslip' object has no attribute 'action_email_payslip_send'

Comment: That error is because Odoo does not know that you have added that method in Python... could be because you have to include the *.py file where you pasted the Python code I write you in the `__init__.py`, and restart Odoo.

Comment: Still I am getting the same error on restart. Here is the github repo https://github.com/kshirodpatel/email-payslip . Let me know what I am missing.

Comment: In `model.py`, replace `from odoo import models, fields` by `from odoo import models, fields, api, _`. We are using libraries that you are not importing.

Comment: Do you mean how to add a PDF to the salary slip email template?

Comment: Yes. I want to attache the PDF automatically to the template.

Comment: Add this to your email template: `<field name="report_template" ref="the_external_xml_id_of_the_report_you_want_to_attach"/>` and `<field name="report_name">A custom name for the downloaded file</field>`.

Comment: The external xml id would be hr_payroll.model_hr_payslip ?

Comment: I want the payslilip details in the pdf attachment in my case.

Comment: No, that is not the external XML ID. You want to attach a report to the email template. That report must already exist, if not, you have to do the whole report in Qweb language. Once it exists, you have to put its external XML ID in the line I wrote you above. Explaining how to do that is too long. I recommend you to simplify your questions and ask those details in different posts. If not, none is going to answer all of them in a single answer. Please, I think the main question of this one is solved.

Comment: can you help me here in another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108578/odoo-11-add-different-action-menu-in-two-different-area-for-the-same-model

Comment: Check out the `email_from` in the XML of the email template, because I had a syntax error, a missing parenthesis. I have edited this answer to correct it.