# Odoo 11 store attachments to other db

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

In Odoo 11 I want to store the attachment in a different database. So to achieve that I need to get the file once uploaded. So for that I have made my code like this

```
import logging
from odoo import fields
from odoo import models,api
import base64

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class AttachmentStorage(models.Model):

    _name = "attachment.storage"
    _inherit = 'ir.attachment'

    @api.model
    def _file_write(self, value, checksum):
        bin_value = base64.b64decode(value)
        printf(bin_value)
        fname, full_path = self._get_path(bin_value, checksum)
        printf(full_path)
```

But here when I am updating or adding any profile image of an employee(as I am using hr module) this doesn't showing any thing even I am doing printf.

So can someone tell me how to achieve this? I want to store all the attachments in the different db.

**NOTE:** I have installed Odoo using docker on my local system

Comment: Declare the log variable out of the class, just below the libraries call, this way: `_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`. Then use the variable to print what you want in the Odoo log: `_logger.critical(full_path)`. You can use several level log messages.

Comment: Did you try to set `data_dir` to another location in the Odoo config file?

Comment: @CZoellner nope I have not done that. But it should show some error when I am doing printf. In the odoo-server.log also can't see anything related to this.

FYI: I am using docker for odoo.

Comment: @forvas I have used logger but still I am not getting any error related to that. FYI I am using docker

Comment: If you use Docker, you have to built a new image?

Comment: @CZoellner I am already running it with an image. So no worries about that.

Comment: That is not what i meant. If you use the official dockerfiles, maybe you're capable to find out how to do it in the container -> https://github.com/odoo/docker/blob/c6b79809f0772c419f681889b810ae4aaff8ec37/11.0/Dockerfile. But normally you just rebuild the image with an updated Dockerfile...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194768/discussion-between-newuser-and-czoellner).